# How to merge different csv files in a folder into a single csv file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have 40 csv files in a folder and I need to convert into a single csv file? The problem I face is though the body of csv's are the same the headings are different across sheets how do I correct them and merge?

Comment: yeah, solved I still have some more doubts on other areas of handling csv's which I will post.

Comment: @jezrael I have some doubts on the above question could you please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this,

read the files without header, by default it will put range(length_of_the_columns). then concat your df's finally create your header.

```
import os
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame()
for file_ in os.listdir(folder_path):
    temp=pd.read_csv(folder_path+'/'+file_,header=None,skiprows=1)
    df=pd.concat([df,temp],ignore_index=True)

df.columns=[new_column_names]
df.to_csv('single_file.csv',index=False)
```

Comment: @jezrael I have some doubts on the above question could you please help?